# Java: String pattern : how to specify regex for all alpha characters with special characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to be sure that a String contains only alpha characters (with special character like `"é", "è", "ç", "Ç", "ï"`, etc etc.).

I did that, but with special characters returns false...

```
if (myString.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+$")) {
    return true;
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you want to match [only Latin letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707836/latin-letter-regular-expression-in-java) or letters from all alphabets? The `\p{L}` expression matches tens of thousands of characters from many alphabets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Unicode Category](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html): `\\p{L}` or `\\P{Letter}` to match any kind of letter from any language.

```
if (myString.matches("\\p{L}+")) {
    return true;
}
```

BTW, [`String.matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) try to match entire string, so `^`, `$` anchors are not necessary.

Comment: falsetru, with the space character ?

Comment: @anthony, You can use character class together to match both: `[\\s\\p{L}]+`